# Magnitude of the projection of one vector on another one, and viceversa

Tags: vectors

When is the magnitude of the projection of vector $\mathbf{a}$ on vector $\mathbf{b}$ equal to the magnitude of the projection of vector $\mathbf{b}$ on $\mathbf{a}$?

Unsure when this is true.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint, compare the formulas for $proj_uv$and $proj_vu$

Answer (score 1):

For non-zero $a, b$:
$$
\lvert a \cdot b/ \lVert b \rVert \rvert = 
\lVert a \rVert \lvert \cos \angle(a,b) \rvert \\
\lvert b \cdot a/ \lVert a \rVert \rvert = 
\lVert b \rVert \lvert \cos \angle(a,b) \rvert
$$
Both are equal if the vectors are perpendicular or have same magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

You need $\|\mathbf{a}\| = \|\mathbf{b}\|$ or orthogonality. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection#Scalar_projection_2)